# Cannot make a network connection using backtrack 5

Tags: networking, bash, backtrack

I am using Backtrack 5
I am in as root, using bash
When I enter service networking start I receive
networking stop/waiting.

I use Kwrite to look at the file /etc/network/interfaces and it says the primary network interface is eth0
auto eth0

I know the network services are OK - because this is a dual boot system - and I have no problems with the Windows 7 side.

I should mention that this issue just started.  In the past service networking start worked just fine.  Now I stuck.  Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
  ifconfig eth0 up
  dhclient eth0
```

Comment: I tried that and got series of echo back statements which indicated that the port was being bound to an IP address.  However when I then entered service networking start, I get back the same message

Comment: works perfectly